# Can any one provide me code for consuming webservices via SOAP in Java ?

Tags: java, web-services, soap

Can any one provide me code for consuming webservices via SOAP in java? Actually i am able to consume webservices through HTTP GET and HTTP POST but my requirement is to consume webservices through SOAP.I tried through SOAP but not getting any output. So plz help me to out from this crisis.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The WSDL is here:

http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx?WSDL

You can view my example web service client on [github](https://github.com/aliasmrchips/WebServiceClient).  I use the maven cxf-codegen-plugin (as configured in [pom.xml](https://github.com/aliasmrchips/WebServiceClient/blob/master/pom.xml)) to generate the client code, which is located [here](https://github.com/aliasmrchips/WebServiceClient/tree/master/target/generated-sources/cxf/net/webservicex).  You can then call the web service operations as demonstrated [here](https://github.com/aliasmrchips/WebServiceClient/blob/master/src/test/java/net/webservicex/WebServiceTest.java).

Comment: Thnx a lot . You did a good effort.Actually our requirement is that without knowing WSDL, make a request to server with SOAP body approach. I tried by creating Call object then set TargetObjectURI, MethodName, EncodingStyleURI, add parameters and then invoke. But getting some errors..... So in that context plz help me.

Comment: I added a method to [WebServiceTest](https://github.com/aliasmrchips/WebServiceClient/blob/master/src/test/java/net/webservicex/WebServiceTest.java) that just does a POST of the raw SOAP envelope to the web service endpoint.  No cxf, no jaxb... simple yet effective.

Comment: I am very thankful 2 u. Really this is what i m looking for. Thnx a lot. I will take your help further once my project will start, at that time i will know the full requirement of client.:)

Comment: Great!  If you like my answer, would you be so kind as to accept it?

Comment: Hi, will u try with SOAP approach, by creating Call class object then set TargetObjectURI, MethodName, EncodingStyleURI, add parameters and then call invoke method.

Answer (score 0):

If you search in google for `java soap client example` then you will find a lot of java examples of SOAP implementation.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the WSDL of the web service, you can generate a Java client to talk to that service easily with [Axis2 CodeGen](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/userguide-creatingclients.html)

Comment: If you are writing the code by hand it really depends on the nature of the service.

Comment: Thnx for your reply Ruwan. But for project requirement client will not provide WSDl.I am writing the code to consume SOAP webservices . The service provider is "http://www.webservicex.net". This is the request and response format of the webservices. Plz go through this link: "http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx?op=GetCitiesByCountry" and suggest sample code.

Comment: If you do not have the WSDL and just the sample request messages, why do not you just do an HTTP POST with a library like [httpcore](http://hc.apache.org)

Comment: Thnx again Ruwan. I have implemented through HTTP POST and HTTP GET,getting output also.No problem with it. But thing is that my project is going to start and till now its not clear that in which way client will accept our request whether it is HTTP POST/GET or SOAP. So before starting that project i want to complete my homework in all possible ways to sending the request to the server. One thing is clear that client will not provide us WSDL file. I tried to consume webservices through SOAP by creating Call object. But getting some error.Plz provide sample code from your busy time schedule.